# Index with few seeks and many updates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, index-tuning, nonclustered-index

Say I create a nonclustered index on a table. After a week I look at the sats, e.g. number of seeks, scans, updates etc. E.g. say I have 10 seeks and 10000 updates. How can I measure the cost of the 10000 updates? That is how can I measure the cost of the 10000 updates on the nonclustered index vs 10 extra scans on the clustered index?

I want to learn when the cost of having the index is more than the benefit. How do I measure this?

Comment: You should really check Brent Ozar's sp_blitzindex and check his videos https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/

Comment: Do you have a performance problem with your updates to this table? Presumably you made this index for a reason - did it help with it? It’s important not to worry about the wrong metrics

Comment: @AndrewSayer. I have solved the problem with the table with the other indexes I have created. I just want to learn to make these decisions. E.g. the CI now has 100000 seeks everyday and performance is a lot better. I can't even put a number on the difference... But I want to learn when the cost of having the index is more than the benefit.

Comment: Do you have query store enabled?

Comment: @AliRazeghi. No, what can I find there to help with my quesiton?

Comment: What do you mean by "cost of having the index is more than the benefit". If you mean in raw IO, then the question is simple, but ultimately this is very rarely the case - the real question is "Is the cost of this index higher than the *business benefits*" which is a much more complex, less technical operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
```

and then I would test the SELECT statement that produces the seek and the UPDATE statement.

Finally, I would compare the number of pages read by the SELECT with the number of pages written by the UPDATE.

But in general this ratio between seek and updates seems to suggest that your nonclustered index is not valuable. But it really depends on your query needs.

Comment: Thanks I just wait to see if others have a better answer before I accept. Good idea with statistics IO.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on ... what fields, how big index etc....
The ratio is not great but ...
Is it a simple logging table with insert only?
how often do you insert vs how often do you query.
If you query only once a week but do a big select on a multimilion wide table then even the 10 index scans can be ok.....
To summarize,
I would ask what select is running and using the index and what is the performance without the index.